# Replace bookmark text in Word file using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I assume v2.0 is better... they have some nice "how to:..." [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850833.aspx) but bookmarks don't seem to act as obviously as say a Table... a bookmark is defined by **two** XML elements [BookmarkStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.bookmarkstart.aspx) & [BookmarkEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.bookmarkend.aspx). We have some templates with text in as bookmarks and we simply want to replace bookmarks with some other text... no weird formatting is going on but how do I select/replace bookmark text?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's my approach after using you guys as inspiration:

```
  IDictionary<String, BookmarkStart> bookmarkMap = 
      new Dictionary<String, BookmarkStart>();

  foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in file.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
  {
      bookmarkMap[bookmarkStart.Name] = bookmarkStart;
  }

  foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in bookmarkMap.Values)
  {
      Run bookmarkText = bookmarkStart.NextSibling<Run>();
      if (bookmarkText != null)
      {
          bookmarkText.GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = "blah";
      }
  }
```

Comment: you are following a very simple pattern here which will not work in all cases. In many cases bookmark replacing gets a lot more complicated which will not work with this algorithm.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it doesn't give me any errors and I confirm its reading the bookmarks but not replacing them with the text.

Comment: this works well but it is very brittle if you cannot limit to text-only, single-word bookmark runs. an example: "BOOKMARK" will work, "BOOKMARK1" will not be found because it gets separated into "BOOKMARK" and "1" (tested with Microsoft Word 2016 on Windows 10, desktop version), ending up with a partial substitution.

Answer (score 11):

Replace bookmarks with a single content (possibly multiple text blocks).

```
public static void InsertIntoBookmark(BookmarkStart bookmarkStart, string text)
{
    OpenXmlElement elem = bookmarkStart.NextSibling();

    while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
    {
        OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
        elem.Remove();
        elem = nextElem;
    }

    bookmarkStart.Parent.InsertAfter<Run>(new Run(new Text(text)), bookmarkStart);
}
```

First, the existing content between start and end is removed. Then a new run is added directly behind the start (before the end).

However, not sure if the bookmark is closed in another section when it was opened or in different table cells, etc. ..

For me it's sufficient for now.

Comment: Note, I've translated this answer (with a _lot_ of help from Google). Please check it for accuracy. In the future, please post in English.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, just make sure to add the following lines to save the changes back to your document, file.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save(); file.Close(); file is the file you opened using  WordprocessingDocument.Open("path", true)

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of hours, I have written this method:

```
    Public static void ReplaceBookmarkParagraphs(WordprocessingDocument doc, string bookmark, string text)
    {
        //Find all Paragraph with 'BookmarkStart' 
        var t = (from el in doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                 where (el.Name == bookmark) &&
                 (el.NextSibling<Run>() != null)
                 select el).First();
        //Take ID value
        var val = t.Id.Value;
        //Find the next sibling 'text'
        OpenXmlElement next = t.NextSibling<Run>();
        //Set text value
        next.GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = text;

        //Delete all bookmarkEnd node, until the same ID
        deleteElement(next.GetFirstChild<Text>().Parent, next.GetFirstChild<Text>().NextSibling(), val, true);
    }
```

After that, I call:

```
Public static bool deleteElement(OpenXmlElement parentElement, OpenXmlElement elem, string id, bool seekParent)
{
    bool found = false;

    //Loop until I find BookmarkEnd or null element
    while (!found && elem != null && (!(elem is BookmarkEnd) || (((BookmarkEnd)elem).Id.Value != id)))
    {
        if (elem.ChildElements != null && elem.ChildElements.Count > 0)
        {
            found = deleteElement(elem, elem.FirstChild, id, false);
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
            elem.Remove();
            elem = nextElem;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        if (elem == null)
        {
            if (!(parentElement is Body) && seekParent)
            {
                //Try to find bookmarkEnd in Sibling nodes
                found = deleteElement(parentElement.Parent, parentElement.NextSibling(), id, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (elem is BookmarkEnd && ((BookmarkEnd)elem).Id.Value == id)
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

This code is working good if u have no empty Bookmarks. 
I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 4):

I just figured this out 10 minutes ago so forgive the hackish nature of the code.

First I wrote a helper recursive helper function to find all the bookmarks:

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, BookmarkEnd> FindBookmarks(OpenXmlElement documentPart, Dictionary<string, BookmarkEnd> results = null, Dictionary<string, string> unmatched = null )
{
    results = results ?? new Dictionary<string, BookmarkEnd>();
    unmatched = unmatched ?? new Dictionary<string,string>();

    foreach (var child in documentPart.Elements())
    {
        if (child is BookmarkStart)
        {
            var bStart = child as BookmarkStart;
            unmatched.Add(bStart.Id, bStart.Name);
        }

        if (child is BookmarkEnd)
        {
            var bEnd = child as BookmarkEnd;
            foreach (var orphanName in unmatched)
            {
                if (bEnd.Id == orphanName.Key)
                    results.Add(orphanName.Value, bEnd);
            }
        }

        FindBookmarks(child, results, unmatched);
    }

    return results;
}
```

That returns me a Dictionary that I can use to part through my replacement list and add the text after the bookmark:

```cs
var bookMarks = FindBookmarks(doc.MainDocumentPart.Document);

foreach( var end in bookMarks )
{
    var textElement = new Text("asdfasdf");
    var runElement = new Run(textElement);

    end.Value.InsertAfterSelf(runElement);
}
```

From what I can tell inserting into and replacing the bookmarks looks harder.  When I used InsertAt instead of InsertIntoSelf I got: "Non-composite elements do not have child elements."  YMMV

Comment: I suppose what I want to do is use start/end bookmark tags to let me select a portion of text (a run?) and modify it. It seems pretty random where the bookmarks are stored though, mine are all in `doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants`

Comment: @John They are inside the tree at the place in the document they were added.  Nothing random about it at all.  Everything is going to be in Body.Descendants.  Body.Elements only gets first level children.  Wait, maybe I should just be searching Descendants...

Answer (score 3):

I took the code from the answer, and had several problems with it for exceptional cases:

1. You might want to ignore hidden bookmarks. Bookmarks are hidden if the name starts with an _ (underscore)
2. If the bookmark is for one more more TableCell's, you will find it in the BookmarkStart in the first Cell of the row with the property ColumnFirst refering to the 0-based column index of the cell where the bookmark starts. ColumnLast refers to the cell where the bookmark ends, for my special case it was always ColumnFirst == ColumnLast (bookmarks marked only one column). In this case you also won't find a BookmarkEnd.
3. Bookmarks can be empty, so a BookmarkStart follows directly a BookmarkEnd, in this case you can just call 
   `bookmarkStart.Parent.InsertAfter(new Run(new Text("Hello World")), bookmarkStart)`
4. Also a bookmark can contain many Text-elements, so you might want to Remove all the other elements, otherwise parts of the Bookmark might be replaced, while other following parts will stay.
5. And I'm not sure if my last hack is necessary, since I don't know all the limitations of OpenXML, but after discovering the previous 4, I also didn't trust anymore that there will be a sibling of Run, with a child of Text. So instead I just look at all my siblings (until BookmarEnd which has the same ID as BookmarkStart) and check all the children until I find any Text. - Maybe somebody with more experience with OpenXML can answer if it is necessary?

You can view my specific implementation [here](http://emptycode.blogspot.com/2013/02/handling-bookmarks-in-openxml-word.html))

Hope this helps some of you who experienced the same issues.

Comment: Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 2):

Most solutions here assume a regular bookmarking pattern of starting before and ending after runs, which is not always true e.g. if bookmark starts in a para or table and ends somewhere in another para (like others have noted). How about using document order to cope with the case where bookmarks are not placed in a regular structure - the document order will still find all the relevant text nodes in between which can then be replaced. Just do root.DescendantNodes().Where(xtext or bookmarkstart or bookmark end) which will traverse in document order, then one can replace text nodes that appear after seeing a bookmark start node but before seeing an end node.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i do it and VB to add/replace text between bookmarkStart and BookmarkEnd.

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:name="forbund_kort" w:id="0" /> 
        - <w:r>
          <w:t>forbund_kort</w:t> 
          </w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />


Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing

    Public Class PPWordDocx

        Public Sub ChangeBookmarks(ByVal path As String)
            Try
                Dim doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, True)
                 'Read the entire document contents using the GetStream method:

                Dim bookmarkMap As IDictionary(Of String, BookmarkStart) = New Dictionary(Of String, BookmarkStart)()
                Dim bs As BookmarkStart
                For Each bs In doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants(Of BookmarkStart)()
                    bookmarkMap(bs.Name) = bs
                Next
                For Each bs In bookmarkMap.Values
                    Dim bsText As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement = bs.NextSibling
                    If Not bsText Is Nothing Then
                        If TypeOf bsText Is BookmarkEnd Then
                            'Add Text element after start bookmark
                            bs.Parent.InsertAfter(New Run(New Text(bs.Name)), bs)
                        Else
                            'Change Bookmark Text
                            If TypeOf bsText Is Run Then
                                If bsText.GetFirstChild(Of Text)() Is Nothing Then
                                    bsText.InsertAt(New Text(bs.Name), 0)
                                End If
                                bsText.GetFirstChild(Of Text)().Text = bs.Name
                            End If
                        End If

                    End If
                Next
                doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Save()
                doc.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to replace the text of a bookmark (bookmarks name is "Table") with a table. This is my approach:

```
public void ReplaceBookmark( DatasetToTable( ds ) )
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
    Body body = mainPart.Document.GetFirstChild<Body>();
    var bookmark = body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                        .Where( o => o.Name == "Table" )
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    var parent = bookmark.Parent; //bookmark's parent element
    if (ds!=null)
    {
        parent.InsertAfterSelf( DatasetToTable( ds ) );
        parent.Remove();
    }
    mainPart.Document.Save();
}


public Table DatasetToTable( DataSet ds )
{
    Table table = new Table();
    //creating table;
    return table;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it in VB.NET:

```
For Each curBookMark In contractBookMarkStarts

      ''# Get the "Run" immediately following the bookmark and then
      ''# get the Run's "Text" field
      runAfterBookmark = curBookMark.NextSibling(Of Wordprocessing.Run)()
      textInRun = runAfterBookmark.LastChild

      ''# Decode the bookmark to a contract attribute
      lines = DecodeContractDataToContractDocFields(curBookMark.Name, curContract).Split(vbCrLf)

      ''# If there are multiple lines returned then some work needs to be done to create
      ''# the necessary Run/Text fields to hold lines 2 thru n.  If just one line then set the
      ''# Text field to the attribute from the contract
      For ptr = 0 To lines.Count - 1
          line = lines(ptr)
          If ptr = 0 Then
              textInRun.Text = line.Trim()
          Else
              ''# Add a <br> run/text component then add next line
              newRunForLf = New Run(runAfterBookmark.OuterXml)
              newRunForLf.LastChild.Remove()
              newBreak = New Break()
              newRunForLf.Append(newBreak)

              newRunForText = New Run(runAfterBookmark.OuterXml)
              DirectCast(newRunForText.LastChild, Text).Text = line.Trim

              curBookMark.Parent.Append(newRunForLf)
              curBookMark.Parent.Append(newRunForText)
          End If
      Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer and some of the others make assumptions about where the bookmarks are in the document structure. Here's my C# code, which can deal with replacing bookmarks that stretch across multiple paragraphs *and* correctly replace bookmarks that do not start and end at paragraph boundaries. Still not perfect, but closer... hope it's useful. Edit if you find more ways to improve it!

```
    private static void ReplaceBookmarkParagraphs(MainDocumentPart doc, string bookmark, IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> paras) {
        var start = doc.Document.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().Where(x => x.Name == bookmark).First();
        var end = doc.Document.Descendants<BookmarkEnd>().Where(x => x.Id.Value == start.Id.Value).First();
        OpenXmlElement current = start;
        var done = false;

        while ( !done && current != null ) {
            OpenXmlElement next;
            next = current.NextSibling();

            if ( next == null ) {
                var parentNext = current.Parent.NextSibling();
                while ( !parentNext.HasChildren ) {
                    var toRemove = parentNext;
                    parentNext = parentNext.NextSibling();
                    toRemove.Remove();
                }
                next = current.Parent.NextSibling().FirstChild;

                current.Parent.Remove();
            }

            if ( next is BookmarkEnd ) {
                BookmarkEnd maybeEnd = (BookmarkEnd)next;
                if ( maybeEnd.Id.Value == start.Id.Value ) {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            if ( current != start ) {
                current.Remove();
            }

            current = next;
        }

        foreach ( var p in paras ) {
            end.Parent.InsertBeforeSelf(p);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with - not 100% perfect but works for simple bookmarks and simple text to insert:

```
private void FillBookmarksUsingOpenXml(string sourceDoc, string destDoc, Dictionary<string, string> bookmarkData)
    {
        string wordmlNamespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
        // Make a copy of the template file.
        File.Copy(sourceDoc, destDoc, true);

        //Open the document as an Open XML package and extract the main document part.
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordPackage = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destDoc, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart part = wordPackage.MainDocumentPart;

            //Setup the namespace manager so you can perform XPath queries 
            //to search for bookmarks in the part.
            NameTable nt = new NameTable();
            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
            nsManager.AddNamespace("w", wordmlNamespace);

            //Load the part's XML into an XmlDocument instance.
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
            xmlDoc.Load(part.GetStream());

            //Iterate through the bookmarks.
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> bookmarkDataVal in bookmarkData)
            {
                var bookmarks = from bm in part.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                          select bm;

                foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
                {
                    if (bookmark.Name == bookmarkDataVal.Key)
                    {
                        Run bookmarkText = bookmark.NextSibling<Run>();
                        if (bookmarkText != null)  // if the bookmark has text replace it
                        {
                            bookmarkText.GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = bookmarkDataVal.Value;
                        }
                        else  // otherwise append new text immediately after it
                        {
                            var parent = bookmark.Parent;   // bookmark's parent element

                            Text text = new Text(bookmarkDataVal.Value);
                            Run run = new Run(new RunProperties());
                            run.Append(text);
                            // insert after bookmark parent
                            parent.Append(run);
                        }

                        //bk.Remove();    // we don't want the bookmark anymore
                    }
                }
            }

            //Write the changes back to the document part.
            xmlDoc.Save(wordPackage.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever have issues with changing/matching font styles/sizes?  I can insert text, but the text size/style that was originally in the template get overwritten with a "default" style of sorts.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Building on [cyberblast’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833457/2385435), here is a simple modification that retains the properties (styling) of the first element inside the Bookmark if it is a Run:

```
static void InsertIntoBookmark(BookmarkStart bookmarkStart, string text)
{
    OpenXmlElement? element = bookmarkStart.NextSibling();
    RunProperties? props = (element as Run)?.RunProperties?.Clone() as RunProperties;

    if (props is null)
        props = bookmarkStart.PreviousSibling<Run>()?.RunProperties?.Clone() as RunProperties;

    while (element is not null && !(element is BookmarkEnd))
    {
        var nextElem = element.NextSibling();
        element.Remove();
        element = nextElem;
    }

    var newRun = new Run(new Text(text));
    newRun.RunProperties = props;

    bookmarkStart.Parent?.InsertAfter(newRun, bookmarkStart);
}
```

If the first thing in the Bookmark is not a Run, I take the properties from the closest Run before the bookmark, because that’s what works for my case. You may want to something else, like search for styling deeper inside the bookmark.