# Replacing content in Word 2010 Textboxes using OpenXML

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, bookmarks, textbox

Using the Open XML SDK I've been successful in programatically finding bookmarks or text strings in a word document and inserting new content.  I'm using OpenXmlPowerTools.SearchAndReplacer to do the text search and replace and this post's answer for the bookmarks [Replace bookmark text in Word file using Open XML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308299/replace-bookmark-text-in-word-file-using-open-xml-sdk)

This all fails when the bookmark or the text I am trying to replace is located inside a Textbox.

Why does neither approach work within a Textbox?  The Word documents I am trying to replace content within use Texboxes for layout and I can't work out what the problem is.

Does anybody have suggestions as to what might be the problem?  Thanks

Comment: A Docx document is basicly a XML document. The approaches you mention probably search for the correct type of tag that has your text as a content. Textbox however might have a completely different tags that your code just ignores. I would check out the underlying XML for a document with a TextBox and see how it's kept in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the XML for a simple textbox with the word test in it:

```
<w:pict xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t202" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="202" path="m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <v:stroke joinstyle="miter" />
    <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect" />
  </v:shapetype>
  <v:shape id="_x0000_s1027" style="position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:186.35pt;height:110.6pt;z-index:251660288;mso-width-percent:400;mso-height-percent:200;mso-position-horizontal:center;mso-width-percent:400;mso-height-percent:200;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin" type="#_x0000_t202" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:t">
      <w:txbxContent>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00B558B5" w:rsidRDefault="00B558B5">
          <w:proofErr w:type="gramStart" />
          <w:r>
            <w:t>test</w:t>
          </w:r>
          <w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd" />
        </w:p>
      </w:txbxContent>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:shape>
</w:pict>
```

You can see the structure is different then when searching for text within a bookmark since a textbox is actually stored as a picture.  If you adjust your searching algorithm to deal with this different structure then you should be able to find the text and replace it.

Answer (score 2):

I did this - it works on text boxes in the case where there are not multiple runs with text (like 1 word bolded

```
    Dim searchQuery = From tx In mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants(Of Text)()
        Where tx.Text.Contains(replaceData.OldText)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To searchQuery.Count - 1
        searchQuery(i).Text = searchQuery(i).Text.Replace(replaceData.OldText, replaceData.NewText)
    Next
```