# PowerDesigner COM object is empty on Windows Server 2012

Tags: powershell, com, windows-server-2012, powerdesigner, ole-automation

We have a problem when scripting PowerDesigner on Windows Server 2012.
We don't have problems on Windows 10 and Windows 7 (we tried it on several machines).

We are starting PowerDesigner from PowerShell like this:

```
$PowerDesigner = New-Object -com powerdesigner.application
Add-Type -path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PowerDesigner 16\Interop.PdCommon.dll”
Add-Type -path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PowerDesigner 16\Add-ins\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Analysis Service\Interop.PdPDM.dll”
```

On Windows Server 2012 R2 all properties of the $PowerDesigner object are set to $null. 
If we try to set a property to some other value we get an error.
For example, the statement

```
$PowerDesigner.InteractiveMode = 1
```

fails with the following error:

```
Exception setting "InteractiveMode": "Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))"
```

The PowerDesigner version is 16.1.0.3637.

Comment: Have you tested with 32- or 64-bit versions of Windows 10/7?

Comment: In the same direction, do you have a 64-bit version of PowerDesigner?
I found this mention of problems with using a 32-bit COM object, in a 64-bit environment... https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

Comment: I have tested with 64-bit version of Windows 10/7.

Comment: Are you running the script interactively, or from a service? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425803/office-automation-interop-on-windows-server-2012) about background service "station"...

Comment: I am running the script interactively.