# How to read tables from a particular place in a document?

Tags: c#, ms-word

When I use the below line It reads all tables of that particular document:

```
  foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tableContent in document.Tables)
```

But I want to read tables of a particular content for example from one identifier to another identifier.

Identifier can be in the form of **[SRS oraganisation_123]** to another identifier **[SRS Oraganisation_456]**

I want to read the tables only in between the above mentioned identifiers.

Suppose 34th page contains my identifier so I want read all tables from that point to until I come across my second identifier. I don't want to read remaining tables.

Please ask me for any clarification in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say start and end Identifiers are stored in variables called `myStartIdentifier` and `myEndIdentifier` -

```
    Range myRange = doc.Range();
    int iTagStartIdx = 0;
    int iTagEndIdx = 0;

    if (myRange.Find.Execute(myStartIdentifier))
        iTagStartIdx = myRange.Start;

    myRange = doc.Range();    
    if (myRange.Find.Execute(myEndIdentifier))
        iTagEndIdx = myRange.Start;

    foreach (Table tbl in doc.Range(iTagStartIdx,iTagEndIdx).Tables)
    {
       // Your code goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through following code, if it helps you.

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
           foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Cell c in r.Cells)
            {
                if(c.Range.Text=="Content you want to compare")
                  dt.Columns.Add(c.Range.Text);
            }
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Row row in newTable.Rows)
            {
                System.Data.DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Range.Text)&&(cell.Range.Text=="Text you want to compare with"))
                    {
                        dr[i] = cell.Range.Text; 
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                i++;
            }
```

Go through following linked 3rd number answer.

[Replace bookmark text in Word file using Open XML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308299/replace-bookmark-text-in-word-file-using-open-xml-sdk)

Comment: The content that I want to compare will not be in tables, what I want is, to read tables from one bookmark to another bookmark..!!

Comment: @CharanGourishetty go through link i provided

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your program is structured... but if you can access the identifier in tableContent then you should be able to write a LINQ query.

```
var identifiers = new List<string>();
identifiers.Add("myIdentifier");

var tablesWithOnlyTheIdentifiersIWant = document.Tables.Select(tableContent => identifiers.Contains(tableContent.Identifier)

foreach(var tableContent in tablesWithOnlyTheIdentifiersIWant)
{
     //Do something
}
```

Comment: My identifier will not in table content... :(

Comment: where is that data stored?

Comment: Suppose 34th page contains my identifier so i want read all tables from that point to untill I come across my second identifier. I don't want to read remaining tables.

Comment: Is the identifier a string that is unique to only Identifiers?

Comment: Yes It is a string and it is unique (I could read those identifiers in to a List)

Comment: Then, when you read the document, search for the first Identifier and start reading / saving those tables to a list and stop reading once you reach the identifier you want to stop on.

Comment: Also, using interop is deathly slow.  All office 2007 and later documents are an Open XML base type... Its exponentialy faster to read the documents using the Open XML SDK or third party wrapper such as EPPlus.

Comment: Yeah That's what I want, How to read from that particular identifier and to end at next identifier..?

Comment: if you can read the identifiers into a list, then you just answered your last question

Comment: So what is the code for reading tables only from that identifier to next ? I know code only for reading all tables in a document.