# Reading Word Bookmarks using Open XML and C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, bookmarks

I have read everything I can find that is even remotely related to this (including [Read Word bookmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929213/read-word-bookmarks)), but have not been able to get anything to work.

I am trying to walk through a Word document that has bookmarks in it, and get the values for each of the bookmarks.  I can walk the document and get the names of the bookmarks, but cannot figure out how to get the value/text of the bookmark.

Here is what I am using to get the bookmark names:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(athleteFile, false))
{
    foreach (BookmarkStart bookmark in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
    {       
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(bookmark.Name + " - " + bookmark.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd highly recommend you use the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5), that way you'll have a better idea of what you're working with.

Secondly a bookmark in Word does not have any value associated with it. It is usually marks a location in the word document. So what you're trying to do wont work.

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:name="bkStart" w:id="0" />
```

that is the XML element that is created in the docx file when you add a bookmark to the document.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to use the SDK (I guess I should have included that in the description).  I looked at the XML and found that because of the use of textboxes and drop-downs in the documents, trying to get the data was going to be difficult, and since this was a one-off utility, I just went ahead and used the automation object.

Comment: great! glad I'm glad I was of help. :)

Comment: The link is dead. I suspect they moved it to the new *DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing* assembly.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I have updated the link, the download is now available on their github.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1:

Get the bookmarks text by accessing its **parent's inner text**:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(athleteFile, false))
{
    foreach (BookmarkStart bookmark in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
    {       
        // Get name of bookmark
        string bookmarkNameOriginal = bookmark.Name;

        // Get bookmark text from parent elements text
        string bookmarkText = bookmark.Parent.InnerText;
    }
}
```

---

## Solution 2:

I have found another solution using [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX) by Xceed.

**Note:**
*[Reading bookmarks is slow](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/issues/219) in free version (v1.3 Docx). However it is fixed in v1.4 of Docx (free version is slower to get this update).*

#### Import DocX:

```
using Xceed.Words.NET;
```

#### Create method to read bookmark name and text:

```
/// <summary>
/// Read bookmark text/names in word document
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filePath"></param>
/// <remarks>
/// Uses free DocX by Xceed
/// </remarks>
public void ReadBookmarks(string filePath)
{
    //Load document
    using (DocX Document = DocX.Load(filePath))
    {
        //This is slow in free version (v1.3 Docx), is fixed in v1.4Docx (free version is slower to get this)
        BookmarkCollection bookmarks = Document.Bookmarks;

        //Iterate over bookmarks in document
        foreach (Bookmark bookmark in bookmarks) {
            //Name of bookmark
            string bookmarkName = bookmark.Name;
            //Text of bookmark, usually a word heading (1, 2, 3...)
            string bookmarkText = bookmark.Paragraph.Text;
        }
    }
}
```